# Is $scope a dependency?

Tags: angularjs, scope, dependencies, code-injection

Here's how I see it. You put in your controller parameter called `$scope`.

AngularJS see that `$scope` parameter and goes and creates that `$scope` object for us and injects it in our controller in that same place where `$scope` parameter was.

So injecting that object in that place is injection right? But what is a dependency? `$scope`? Or that object constructor that creates `$scope`?

Answer (score 0):

A dependency is something a controller depends on.

So in this example:

```
.controller('MyController', function($scope) {});
```

The controller `MyController` has a dependency on `$scope`.

Comment: If scope is not  a dependency, why is it called dependency injection?

Comment: scope **is** a dependency. `MyController` needs `$scope` to be injected. It doesn't care what gets injected into $scope, but `MyController` depends on the fact that something will get injected into `$scope`. AngularJS will see that `MyController` has `$scope` as a dependency and will inject it into the controller.